# Python - weird behavior with Queues, Managers and Multiprocessing

Tags: python, queue, python-multiprocessing

While working on a pet project of mine involving simultaneous downloads using the `multiprocessing` module I encountered a curious behaviour involving `Queue` objects generated by a `multiprocessing.Manager()` object.

Depending on how I put a Queue object (generated through a `Manager`) inside another `Queue` object (also generated through a `Manager`), I get a different behaviour for doing, to my understanding, the same thing.
Here's a minimum working example:

```
import multiprocessing
import Queue

def work(inbound_queue, keep_going):
    while keep_going.value == 1:
        try:
            outbound_queue = inbound_queue.get(False) # this fails in case 3
            #do some work
            outbound_queue.put("work done!")
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass #this is busy wait of course, it's just an example

class Weird:
    def __init__(self):
        self.manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
        self.queue = self.manager.Queue()
        self.keep_going = multiprocessing.Value("i", 1)
        self.worker = multiprocessing.Process(target = work, args = (self.queue, self.keep_going))
        self.worker.start()
    def stop(self): #close and join the second process
        self.keep_going.value = 0
        self.worker.join()
    def queueFromOutside(self, q):
        self.queue.put(q)
        return q
    def queueFromNewManager(self):
        q = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()
        self.queue.put(q)
        return q
    def queueFromOwnManager(self):
        q = self.manager.Queue()
        self.queue.put(q)
        return q

if __name__ == '__main__':
    instance = Weird()
    # CASE 1
    queue = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()
    q1 = instance.queueFromOutside(queue) # Works fine
    print "1: ", q1.get()

    # CASE 2
    q2 = instance.queueFromNewManager()   # Works fine
    print "2: ", q2.get()

    # CASE 3
    q3 = instance.queueFromOwnManager()   # Error
    print "3: ", q3.get()

    instance.stop() #sadly never called :(
```

and its outputs (python 2.7.10 x86, windows).

OUTPUT for main:

```
1:  work done!
2:  work done!
3:
```

then the worker process crashes, leaving q3.get() hanging.

OUTPUT for worker process:

```
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "J:\Dropbox\Python\queues2.py", line 7, in work
    outbound_queue = inbound_queue.get(False) # this fails in case 3
  File "<string>", line 2, in get
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 774, in _callmethod
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
RemoteError:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unserializable message: ('#RETURN', <Queue.Queue instance at 0x025A22B0>)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So the question is: why does the 3rd case cause a `RemoteError`?

The example provided does not resemble the structure of the code in the actual project, but I do send queues to running processes, and it's working fine if I do it with methods #1 and #2. It'd be nice to use method #3 though, since it saves the trouble of getting a `Manager` every time, wich can take surprisingly long (~100 ms on the machine I'm working from right now).

The question comes out of curiosity, as I'm still learning about all the cool things in the `multiprocessing` module.

**UPDATE, trying to clarify the question:** in case 3 (`queueFromOwnManager`) why does `self.manager.Queue()` create a queue that once put in `self.queue`, cannot be retrieved with `self.queue.get()`, while a queue created with `multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()` can be retrieved? The order of the execution of the 3 cases does not matter. Ideally, `instance.queue` will be empty before and after any of the 3 method calls in the 3 examples.

**UPDATE 2:** made the exaple more similar to what I'm actually doing in the code

Comment: Start with q0 instead of q1, that is change q1,q2,q3 to q0,q1,q2 in main for instance.queueFromNewManager()

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer , I've added code in main for populating and printing items placed in the queue self.queue from a list ls. I've also added a statement that can be used for retrieving the items in self.queue from ls in an external function.

```
import multiprocessing
import Queue

def work(inbound_queue, keep_going):
    while keep_going.value == 1:
        try:
            pass
            #outbound_queue = inbound_queue.get(False) # this fails in case 3 #<--- an error here, wherefrom does it get truthvalues?
            #do some work
            #outbound_queue.put("work done!")
        except: #Queue.Empty:                            <--- self.queue.Empty(): when instantiated below
            pass #this is busy wait of course, it's just an example

class Weird:
    def __init__(self):
        self.manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
        self.queue = self.manager.Queue()
        self.queue2 = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()
        self.keep_going = multiprocessing.Value("i", 1)
        self.worker = multiprocessing.Process(target = work, args = (self.queue, self.keep_going))
        self.worker.start()
    def stop(self): #close and join the second process
        self.keep_going.value = 0
        #self.worker.join()
    def queueFromOutside(self, q):

        ls = [1,2,3,4,5]
        # populate self.queue with elements from list ls
        for i in ls:
          self.queue.put(i)
        return self.queue
    def queueFromNewManager(self):
         #q = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()  <---- note that you state that manager and not "queue"
                                                      # is the name of the queue in this step,
                                                      # therefor errormsg, at this step manager
                                                     # is empty and self.queue has been given ls


        ls = [5,6,7,8]
        # populate self.queue with elements from list ls
        for i in ls:

          self.queue.put(i)
        return self.queue


    def queueFromOwnManager(self):
        q = self.manager.Queue()


        ls = [5,6,7,8]
        # populate self.queue with elements from list ls
        for i in ls:
          self.queue.put(i)
        return self.queue

    def wait_completion(self):     #<---- function that waits until tasks are done, and joins all
                                            # tasks as a last step, check docs how to add tasks and data to manager
        """Wait for completion of all the tasks in the queue"""
        self.tasks.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    instance = Weird()
    # CASE 1

    q1 = instance.queueFromOutside(instance.queue2) # Works fine
    print "1: ", q1.get()

    #this code gets data from instance.queue in external functions
    if not instance.queue.empty():

        item = instance.queue.get(True)
        print item,"item"

    # CASE 2
    q2 = instance.queueFromNewManager()   # Works fine
    print "2: ", q2.get()

    # CASE 3
    q3 = instance.queueFromOwnManager()   # Error
    print "3: ", q3.get()

    instance.stop() #sadly never called :(

    # when all tasks done  wait_completion(self) can be printed here to join all tasks
```

Comment: Looks like I asked the question in a weird way since this doesn't really answer it, see the updated question :)

Comment: ok, as I understood your first question it was about that error but anyhow, "cannot be retrieved with self.queue.get()", you can retrieve self.queue.get()  it the main - class by looping for i in object.queue... It's difficult to answer without a concrete example but have you written a join() function or where do you join the tasks?

Comment: Changed the example a bit to reflect what I'm doing in the project. The problem is that the worker process can't retrieve queues if they're created with a manager saved as an attribute of the class `Weird`, but I can't think of a reason that explains this behaviour.

Comment: I've updated the answer and description with code that works for retrieving the data from self.queue

Comment: forgot the import; import Queue

Comment: to answer case 3; note that populating queues is done with for loops, so queue(put) hasn't worked and populated the queues. multiprocessing.Manager().Queue() is another type of queue that works differently than self.queue, a regular Queue class instance. Populate the manager like this;  ls = manager.list([1, [1], [1]]) or di = manager.dict({0: 1, 1: [1], 2:[1]}) print 'before', ns, ls, di p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=(ns, ls, di)), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436757/how-does-multiprocessing-manager-work-in-python