# Python pickler.load() throwing FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, file, pickle

I'm having a strange issue where Python will successfully find and read a binary file that exists, but `pickle.load()` will not. `pickle.load()` is throwing a FileNotFoundError which doesn't make much sense. I know for a fact the file is there because if I try to read the contents of the file I'm able to.

```
try:
    with open("test", "rb") as f:
        print(f.read())
        data = pickle.load(f)

except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print(e)
```

I've been trying to wrap my head around this for a few hours now and I just can't understand what's going on here. I've had my fair share of Python and never had this happen to me. Working on Windows 10 with VSCode and WSL (Ubuntu 20.04).

EDIT: I know this particular code won't work because I'm reading with  `f.read()` first. I just put it there to show that it works, I only really want to `pickle.load()` it.

EDIT: Traceback goes like such:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/d/_/Projects/FCUL/SO/pgrepwc/v2/hpgrepwc.py", line 34, in main
    data = pickle.load(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 959, in RebuildProxy
    return func(token, serializer, incref=incref, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 809, in __init__
    self._incref()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 863, in _incref
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 502, in Client
    c = SocketClient(address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 630, in SocketClient
    s.connect(address)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

And as requested, my directory listing:

```
prgrepwc:
    |
    |   histFile1
    |   histFile2
    |   .gitattributes
    |   .gitignore
    |   testFile
    |
    +---.vscode
    |       launch.json
    |       settings.json
    |
    |
    \---v2
        |
        |   testFile
        |   histFile
        |   hpgrepwc.py
        |   Load.py
        |   Match.py
        |   pgrepwc_v2.py
        \-- README.txt
```

The file I'm executing is `hpgrepwc.py` in folder `v2`. The file I'm trying to read is the binary file `testFile`. I've noticed even though my script is in folder `v2`, it defaults to `pgrepwc` sometimes so I even placed a copy of `testFile` on there just in case. No dice either way, I've also tried to save the file as `.bin` to no avail.

SOLUTION:

@tdelaney mentioned:

> "(...) it looks like some object created in a multiprocessing.Manager
> was pickled.  But these objects are actually proxies that broadcast
> changes to a group of subprocesses and are not valid outside of that
> context.  In your case, the unpickler tried to reconstruct a class
> that tried to reconnect to its long-dead multiprocessing partners.
> You need to look to the code doing the pickling and figure out some
> other way to encapsulate the data."

This was exactly it. I make heavy use of `multiprocessing.Manager` for shared memory data structures in my code. After converting a `manager.dict()` to a regular Python `dict`, the pickling and unpickling worked like a charm. Once again, thanks to everyone who contributed and especially @tdelaney.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback message?

Comment: The file you use should be of the extension `.pickle`. So re-dump the pickle under the name of `test.pickle` then open `test.pickle`.

Comment: @NavaneethReddy - pickle doesn't know or care about the file name. Its an open file, pickle reads it.

Comment: This code won't work because you've read to end of file before trying to unpickle. That should result in an EOFError, not FileNotFoundError. If the error is on the `open` call, then the problem is just that there isn't a file called "test" in the current working directory. I asked for the traceback so that we can see both the full error message and the failing line.

Comment: @tdelaney if you have a file without any extension, that is considered a folder. That's why programmers choose the extension `.pickle` by convention.

Comment: Are you sure the exception being thrown is `FileNotFoundError` and not `EOFError`? Trying to replicate what you did simply gives me an `EOFError` because I assume that the call to `f.read()` moves the file pointer to EOF. Removing the call to `f.read()` was enough to get it working.

Comment: @NavaneethReddy -That is not correct. Files do not need extensions on them. Microsoft Windows lets you associate programs to files via the file extension and will not execute code unless it has an `.exe` or other well-defined extension. Unix-like systems don't work that way and don't usually care what the exention (if any) is. In this case, OP opened the file and passed the file handle to pickle. Pickle just reads that file and doesn't care in the least where it came from.

Comment: @DakshrajSharma This code will not throw an EOF error since `open('file.name', 'rb') as f` doesn't actually read the file.

Comment: @DakshrajSharma Also `.read()` is a blocking function and no buffer is specified. So the program will not resume till `.read()` is complete.

Comment: @DakshrajSharma As I'm only excepting that error, I'm sure it's FileNotFoundError.
@tdelaney I would but it actually doesn't give me any, just `"Errno 2] No such file or directory: testFile"`

Comment: @NavaneethReddy, you're right it doesn't. But the very next line `print(f.read())` does.

Comment: @zeval - but the read worked? You could add `import traceback;traceback.print_exc()` to your exception handler to print the traceback so that we can see where the program failed.

Comment: @Zeval a listing of your directory contents and some more code context could be helpful!

Comment: @Zeval I have just tested `open` and I am right, you absolutely need to specify the file extension along with the name. You can only exclude file extensions when the file itself doesn't have an extension.

Comment: The read works, that's what's weird. I'll try to get the traceback and report back.

Comment: Pickle needs to import modules and create class instances during load. Its possible that you have a class that attempts to open a file in that process. That would fail if the file didn't exist in the unpickling environment and basically means that the class is unpickleable. We would see the error deep in the bowels of pickle in the traceback in that case.

Comment: @Zeval Well the function doesn't actually get to `.read()` anything since the `open` line above is throwing a `FileNotFound` error.

Comment: @Zeval So technically the read is not reachable but will work once the file name is fixed.

Comment: @Zeval are you using multiprocessing/processes in your code? Could this be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56641428/python-3-6-nested-multiprocessing-managers-cause-filenotfounderror. The error seems somewhat relevant to the one described in this question

Comment: With that edit, it looks like some object created in a `multiprocessing.Manager` was pickled. But these objects are actually proxies that broadcast changes to a group of subprocesses and are not valid outside of that context. In your case, the unpickler tried to reconstruct a class that tried to reconnect to its long-dead multiprocessing partners. You need to look to the code doing the pickling and figure out some other way to encapsulate the data.

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, that might be the problem, too.

Comment: @tdelaney Thank you! That makes perfect sense!! I make heavy use of `multiprocessing.Manager` on my main program, to make a dictionary available to all subprocesses, which works wonderfully fast and a lot better than all the other alternatives I've tried, it's absolutely invaluable to the code. What I could do is try to convert the `multiprocessing.Manager().dict()` to a regular dictionary. I'll try that, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: From the traceback we see `File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 959, in RebuildProxy` - so a multiprocessing manager was part of what was pickled. The problem is on the side that did `pickle.dump`. It pickled an object that can't be unpickled. We need to look at that code to figure this out.

Comment: Great to hear. I think that is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do not have multiprocessing.Manager objects in your class or object. I had a multiprocessing.Manager().dict() in my object. So I replaced that with a normal dict and everything works fine now.

Answer (score -1):

So pickling a file with an extension of `.pkl` or `.pickle` is recommended.

So re-dump the file with an extension first.

```
with open('test.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(your_contents, f)
```

then change the `load`ing part to this:

```
try:
    with open("test.pickle", "rb") as f:
        print(f.read())
        data = pickle.load(f)

except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print(e)
```

The python function `open` will read files with extensions. You can only exclude extensions only if the file itself doesn't have an extension.

Comment: No, pickle doesn't care what the file name is. It could be `ThisIsNotAPickleFile.TrustMe` and would read just fine. `pickle.load` doesn't actually open files, it just requires an object with a couple of methods. From the docs _The argument *file* must have two methods, a read() method that takes an integer argument, and a readline() method that requires no arguments._. You can use a reader that pulls in web content, a reader that decompresses first, and etc... Pickle does not know the file name and has no interaction with the file name in any way.

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work for me. I tried `.bin`, `.pickle`, `.pkl`, none of them worked, but then again it's UNIX so that wouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @tdelaney That's what I was telling you in the previous comment section. Pickle doesn't care about the file extension, but `.pickle` extension is used just as per convention. Also on windows, `open` will only read files if extension is specified.

Comment: @Zeval If you are on unix, try cPickle instead of pickle.

Comment: @tdelaney Yes true, pickle doesn't care about the filename, but you need to put a reference of that file inside the load, how else you'd do that, by providing a full file name with the extension to the `open` function.

Comment: @NavaneethReddy I've used pickle in other projects before, and right now I'm using custom objects inside the pickled object which I'm not sure cPickle supports.

Comment: @tdelaney I never said `pickle` cares and doesn't care about the file name at the same time. Yes, the file name can be anything., but to actually `load` it, you have to have a reference to the object in the second parameter of `load` and that parameter has to be an object of `open`. Try this code first then we can discuss the errors.

Comment: @Zeval I am not sure neither, but I have seen unix users using `cPickle` instead of `pickle`. I use `pickle` since I'm a windows user. But we are programmers, we just try stuff until it tends to work right.

Comment: @NavaneethReddy True that. And I thank you for the suggestion, but I'm obliged to either use pickle or struct for this task, and I'd much rather go with pickle.

Comment: @tdelaney To be fair, I don't really understand what's going on from the traceback, sorry.

Comment: @Zeval - lets discuss that above.