# Python multiprocessing not working as intended with fuzzywuzzy

Tags: python, multithreading, duplicates, multiprocessing, fuzzywuzzy

Either my processes kicking off one after another finishes or they start (simultaneously) but without calling the pointing function. I tried many variants somehow it will not act like many tutorials teach.
My Goal is to fuzzywuzzy String match a 80k item list of text sentences, droping unneccessary 90%+ matches while keeping the String with the most information (scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio).
Thank you!

IDE is Anaconda Spyder 4.0, IPython 7.10.1, Python 3.7.5

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing
import time
from datetime import datetime
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

#########
preparedDF = []
df1 = []
df2 = []
df3 = []
df4 = []
df5 = []
df6 = []
df7 = []
df8 = []
#########
xdf1 = []
xdf2 = []
xdf3 = []
xdf4 = []
xdf5 = []
xdf6 = []
xdf7 = []
xdf8 = []
#########

def fuzzyPrepare():
    #load data do some easy cleaning
    global preparedDF
    df = pd.read_csv("newEN.csv")
    df = df["description"].fillna("#####").tolist()
    df = list(dict.fromkeys(df))
    try:
        df = df.remove("#####")
    except ValueError:
        pass
    preparedDF=df

def fuzzySplit(df=preparedDF):
    #split data to feed processes
    global df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8
    df1 = df[:100]
    df2 = df[100:200]
    df3 = df[200:300]
    df4 = df[300:400]
    df5 = df[400:500]
    df6 = df[500:600]
    df7 = df[600:700]
    df8 = df[700:800]

def fuzzyMatch(x):
    #process.dedupe returns dict_keys object so pass it to a list()
    global xdf1, xdf2, xdf3, xdf4, xdf5, xdf6, xdf7, xdf8
    if x == 1:
        xdf1=list(process.dedupe(df1,threshold=90,scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio))
    elif x == 2:
        xdf2=list(process.dedupe(df2,threshold=90,scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio))
    elif x == 3:
        xdf3=list(process.dedupe(df3,threshold=90,scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio))
    elif x == 4:
        xdf4=list(process.dedupe(df4,threshold=90,scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio))
    elif x == 5:
        xdf5=list(process.dedupe(df5,threshold=90,scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio))
    elif x == 6:
        xdf6=list(process.dedupe(df6,threshold=90,scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio))
    elif x == 7:
        xdf7=list(process.dedupe(df7,threshold=90,scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio))
    elif x == 8:
        xdf8=list(process.dedupe(df8,threshold=90,scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio))
    else:
        return "error in fuzzyCases!"

#if __name__ == '__main__':
fuzzyPrepare()
fuzzySplit(preparedDF)
#UNHEEDED MULTIPROCESSING, ONLY THIS LINE TRIGGERS THE ACTUAL FUNCTION -> p1 = multiprocessing.Process(name="p1",target=fuzzyMatch(1), args=(1,))

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(name="p1",target=fuzzyMatch, args=(1,))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(name="p2",target=fuzzyMatch, args=(2,))
p3 = multiprocessing.Process(name="p3",target=fuzzyMatch, args=(3,))
p4 = multiprocessing.Process(name="p4",target=fuzzyMatch, args=(4,))
p5 = multiprocessing.Process(name="p5",target=fuzzyMatch, args=(5,))
p6 = multiprocessing.Process(name="p6",target=fuzzyMatch, args=(6,))
p7 = multiprocessing.Process(name="p7",target=fuzzyMatch, args=(7,))
p8 = multiprocessing.Process(name="p8",target=fuzzyMatch, args=(8,))

jobs = []
jobs.append(p1)
jobs.append(p2)
jobs.append(p3)
jobs.append(p4)
jobs.append(p5)
jobs.append(p6)
jobs.append(p7)
jobs.append(p8)

for j in jobs:
    print("process "+ j.name +" started at "+ datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
    j.start()
    time.sleep(0.3)

for j in jobs:
    j.join()

print ("processing complete at "+datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: ``multiprocessing`` does not share memory. Changes to globals after spawning a ``Process`` is not visible between processes.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you are dealing with a non-trivial problem here. I have taken the liberty
to DRY ([Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself))
your code a bit. I also dont have your data or pandas installed so I have simplified
the inputs and outputs. The principles however are all the same and with few changes
you should be able to make your code work!

### Attempt #1

I have an array of 800 int elements and each process is going to calculate the
sum of 100 of them. Look for `# DRY:` comments

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import multiprocessing
import time
from datetime import datetime

#########
number_of_proc = 8
preparedDF = []
# DRY: This is now a list of lists. This allows us to refer to df1 as dfs[1]
dfs = []
# DRY: A dict of results. The key will be int (the process number!)
xdf = {}
#########

def fuzzyPrepare():
    global preparedDF
    # Generate fake data
    preparedDF = range(number_of_proc * 100)

def fuzzySplit(df):
    #split data to feed processes
    global dfs
    # DRY: Loop and generate N lists for N processes
    for i in range(number_of_proc):
        from_element = i * 100
        to_element = from_element + 100
        print("Packing [{}, {})".format(from_element, to_element))
        dfs.append(df[from_element:to_element])

def fuzzyMatch(x):
    global xdf
    # DRY: Since we now have a dict, all the if-else is not needed any more...
    xdf[x] = sum(dfs[x])
    print("In process: x={}, xdf[{}]={}".format(x, x, xdf[x]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fuzzyPrepare()
    fuzzySplit(preparedDF)

    # DRY: Create N processes AND append them
    jobs = []
    for p in range(number_of_proc):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(name="p{}".format(p),target=fuzzyMatch, args=(p,))
        jobs.append(p)

for j in jobs:
    print("process "+ j.name +" started at "+ datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
    j.start()
    time.sleep(0.3)

for j in jobs:
    j.join()

print ("processing complete at "+datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
print("results:")
for x in range(number_of_proc):
    print("In process: x={}, xdf[{}]={}".format(x, x, xdf[x]))
```

Output:

```
Packing [0, 100)
Packing [100, 200)
Packing [200, 300)
Packing [300, 400)
Packing [400, 500)
Packing [500, 600)
Packing [600, 700)
Packing [700, 800)
process p0 started at 19:12:00
In process: x=0, xdf[0]=4950
process p1 started at 19:12:00
In process: x=1, xdf[1]=14950
process p2 started at 19:12:00
In process: x=2, xdf[2]=24950
process p3 started at 19:12:01
In process: x=3, xdf[3]=34950
process p4 started at 19:12:01
In process: x=4, xdf[4]=44950
process p5 started at 19:12:01
In process: x=5, xdf[5]=54950
process p6 started at 19:12:01
In process: x=6, xdf[6]=64950
process p7 started at 19:12:02
In process: x=7, xdf[7]=74950
processing complete at 19:12:02
results:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tmp/proctest.py", line 58, in <module>
    print("In process: x={}, xdf[{}]={}".format(x, x, xdf[x]))
KeyError: 0
```

> What happened? I printed the values in the processing function and they were there?!

Well, I am not an expert but a python process works much like `fork()`.
The basic principle is that it will spawn and initialize a new child process. The
child process **will be having a COPY(!) of the parents memory**. This means that
the parent and child processes do not share any data/memory!!!

So in our case:

- We prepare our data
- We create N processes
- Each process has a COPY of `dfs` and `xdf` variables

While for `dfs` we do not care too much (since they are used for input), each
process now has it own `xdf` and not the parent's one! You see why the KeyError?

### How to fix this (Attempt #2)

It is now obvious that we need to return data back from the process to the parent.
There are many ways of doing this but the simpest (code-wise) is to use a
`multiprocessing.Manager` to share data between your child processes (look for `# NEW:`
tag in the code - Note I have only changed 2 lines!):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import multiprocessing
import time
from datetime import datetime

# NEW: This can manage data between processes
from multiprocessing import Manager

#########
number_of_proc = 8
preparedDF = []
dfs = []
# NEW: we create a manager object to store the results
manager = Manager()
xdf = manager.dict()
#########

def fuzzyPrepare():
    global preparedDF
    # Generate fake data
    preparedDF = range(number_of_proc * 100)

def fuzzySplit(df):
    #split data to feed processes
    global dfs
    # DRY: Loop and generate N lists for N processes
    for i in range(number_of_proc):
        from_element = i * 100
        to_element = from_element + 100
        print("Packing [{}, {})".format(from_element, to_element))
        dfs.append(df[from_element:to_element])

def fuzzyMatch(x):
    global xdf
    # DRY: Since we no have a dict, all the if-else is not needed any more...
    xdf[x] = sum(dfs[x])
    print("In process: x={}, xdf[{}]={}".format(x, x, xdf[x]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fuzzyPrepare()
    fuzzySplit(preparedDF)

    # DRY: Create N processes AND append them
    jobs = []
    for p in range(number_of_proc):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(name="p{}".format(p),target=fuzzyMatch, args=(p,))
        jobs.append(p)

for j in jobs:
    print("process "+ j.name +" started at "+ datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
    j.start()
    time.sleep(0.3)

for j in jobs:
    j.join()

print ("processing complete at "+datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
print("results:")
for x in range(number_of_proc):
    print("Out of process: x={}, xdf[{}]={}".format(x, x, xdf[x]))
```

And the output:

```
Packing [0, 100)
Packing [100, 200)
Packing [200, 300)
Packing [300, 400)
Packing [400, 500)
Packing [500, 600)
Packing [600, 700)
Packing [700, 800)
process p0 started at 19:34:50
In process: x=0, xdf[0]=4950
process p1 started at 19:34:50
In process: x=1, xdf[1]=14950
process p2 started at 19:34:50
In process: x=2, xdf[2]=24950
process p3 started at 19:34:51
In process: x=3, xdf[3]=34950
process p4 started at 19:34:51
In process: x=4, xdf[4]=44950
process p5 started at 19:34:51
In process: x=5, xdf[5]=54950
process p6 started at 19:34:52
In process: x=6, xdf[6]=64950
process p7 started at 19:34:52
In process: x=7, xdf[7]=74950
processing complete at 19:34:52
results:
Out of process: x=0, xdf[0]=4950
Out of process: x=1, xdf[1]=14950
Out of process: x=2, xdf[2]=24950
Out of process: x=3, xdf[3]=34950
Out of process: x=4, xdf[4]=44950
Out of process: x=5, xdf[5]=54950
Out of process: x=6, xdf[6]=64950
Out of process: x=7, xdf[7]=74950
```

Read more about this [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) and
note the warning about Manager being slower than a `multiprocessing.Array` (which actually also solves your problem here)

Comment: More interesting info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436757/how-does-multiprocessing-manager-work-in-python) (as I said, not an expert so i read about this myself :) )

Comment: urban thank you for your input.Copy pasting your second attempt is resulting in a non working kernel (no outputs at all, same Environment). I need to restart the kernel because it is freezing somehow.