# how does pool.map save results?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am trying to apply multiprocessing to my script, and I do not understand how `pool.map` is saving the results. This is an example I found:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Pool


def get_listing(url):
    headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36'}
    html = None
    links = None

    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=10)

    if r.status_code == 200:
        html = r.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        listing_section = soup.select('#offers_table table > tbody > tr > td > h3 > a')
        links = [link['href'].strip() for link in listing_section]
    return links


# parse a single item to get information
def parse(url):
    headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=10)
    sleep(2)

    info = []
    title_text = '-'
    location_text = '-'
    price_text = '-'
    title_text = '-'
    images = '-'
    description_text = '-'

    if r.status_code == 200:
        print('Processing..' + url)
        html = r.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        title = soup.find('h1')
        if title is not None:
            title_text = title.text.strip()

        location = soup.find('strong', {'class': 'c2b small'})
        if location is not None:
            location_text = location.text.strip()

        price = soup.select('div > .xxxx-large')
        if price is not None:
            price_text = price[0].text.strip('Rs').replace(',', '')

        images = soup.select('#bigGallery > li > a')
        img = [image['href'].strip() for image in images]
        images = '^'.join(img)

        description = soup.select('#textContent > p')
        if description is not None:
            description_text = description[0].text.strip()

        info.append(url)
        info.append(title_text)
        info.append(location_text)
        info.append(price_text)
        info.append(images)

    return ','.join(info)


car_links = None
cars_info = []
cars_links = get_listing('https://www.olx.com.pk/cars/')

with Pool(10) as p:
    records = p.map(parse, cars_links)

if len(records) > 0:
    with open('data_parallel.csv', 'a+') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(records))
```

What last part `'with Pool(10) as p'` seems to be doing is, multi-processing the parsing process across a number of links in cars_links. However, what I do not understand is **where the records for each url is being stored.** If multi-processing is happening for multiple links at a same time (here, 10 links) - then how are the records being written to csv file?

Also, how would I modify this if I want to save the records to a list? Would this save all the results to a list?

```
with Pool(10) as p:
 records = p.map(parse, cars_links)
 save_records.append(records)
```

Comment: Do you know what a process is? Please study how to share resources. Concurrent/parallel processing is a big subject. To keep it simple, you could use a [Manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers)

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436757/how-does-multiprocessing-manager-work-in-python)