# Managed dictionary does not behave as expected in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

From what I've managed to figure out so far, this may only be a problem in macOS.

Here's my MRE:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
from functools import partial

def foo(d, n):
    d.setdefault("X", []).append(n)

def main():
    with Manager() as manager:
        d = manager.dict()
        with Pool() as pool:
            pool.map(partial(foo, d), range(5))
        print(d)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
{'X': []}
```

**Expected output:**

```
{'X': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

**Platform:**

```
macOS 14.3.1
Python 3.12.2
```

Maybe I'm doing something fundamentally wrong but I understood that the whole point of the Manager was to handle precisely this kind of scenario.

**EDIT**

There is another *hack* which IMHO should be unnecessary but even this doesn't work (produces identical output):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

def ipp(d, lock):
    global gDict, gLock
    gDict = d
    gLock = lock

def foo(n):
    global gDict, gLock
    with gLock:
        gDict.setdefault("X", []).append(n)

def main():
    with Manager() as manager:
        d = manager.dict()
        lock = manager.Lock()
        with Pool(initializer=ipp, initargs=(d, lock)) as pool:
            pool.map(foo, range(5))
        print(d)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I **think** what is going on is that your list inside the dictionary is not being propagated. check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436757/how-to-use-a-multiprocessing-manager though I don't know for sure that is what is happening

Comment: I wonder if someone would kindly run this in a Windows and/or Linux environment for comparison

Comment: I ran in windows with 3.12.2 and see what you see.

Comment: A managed dict only sees direct modifications to its key/value pairs - so I would expect that it gets the empty list assigned to the key "X".  But then you append something to that list, and that doesn't affect the dict *at all* - so there's no way for the change to be propagated to other processes.

Comment: That is my impression as well @jasonharper

Comment: [This is documented.](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-proxy-objects) Search for "the proxy has no way of knowing" for context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a crappy "answer" and I apologize for that and will delete it once you post a comment that you have seen it. I get the distinct impression that the answer is related to the "sub-list" not being managed per that post I mentioned.

For example:

This seems to work:

```
def foo(d, n):
    d.setdefault("X", []).append(n) # the thing being updated is managed

def main():
    with Manager() as manager:
        d = manager.dict()
        d["X"] = manager.list()
        with Pool() as pool:
            pool.map(partial(foo, d), range(5))
        print(list(d["X"]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

as does:

```py
def foo(d, n):
    target = d.setdefault("X", [])
    target.append(n)
    d["X"] = target  # the thing being updated is managed

def main():
    with Manager() as manager:
        d = manager.dict()
        with Pool() as pool:
            pool.map(partial(foo, d), range(5))
        print(d)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So updating a "managed" object seems to work while updating an unmanaged list even inside a managed container object does not.

Comment: I don't think you should delete this. As far as I'm concerned, this is the answer